# Regex: match first x amount of words including special characters and line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
preg_match("/(.+?(?=\s)){7}/", $text, $matches);
```

I am trying to take first x amount of 'words' from a string essentially the regex equivalent of splitting the string on space characters. I am not using \w because I want to include special characters in the 'words'.

I'm hitting issues with line breaks in strings:

https://regexr.com/3nd15

**Example string:**

```
this line doesn't have seven words.
This line does has more than 7 but the regex is ignoring the first line.
```

**Result I get**: (taken from the second line because the first is under 7 words)

```
This line does has more than 7
```

**Result I want**: (line overflow)

```
this line doesn't have seven words. This
```

I've tried adding the multiline flag with no change.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Try [`^\S+(?:\s+\S+){6}`](https://regex101.com/r/ZkPDmi/1), or maybe [without `^`](https://regex101.com/r/ZkPDmi/2/). It would be more helpful to see your code to repro the issue.

Comment: Suggestion, you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php and craft a pattern to match the whitespace and not the words.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to get as the output - `['this line doesn't have seven words.\nThis','line does has more than 7 but','the regex is ignoring the first line.']`?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew , that has the desired effect (the desired output is "this line doesn't have severn words. This" as highlighted in red. @Scuzzy, I am trying to avoid split and joining seperate words as i would just use php's `str_split` in that scenario. But thank you for the suggestion

Comment: A downvote with no explanation is always appreciated.

Comment: @Kiee It seems like the downvote is due to the use of image: the text you are using to test the regex against should be added as text in the post. Also, you still need to add the expected results to the question, as it is unclear for those who do not read comments, and that is 99% of people coming here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the insight, I have removed the screenshot and amended the question to improve for future readers. I just wish people would explain rather than blind downvote.

Comment: They almost never explain. See my answer was downvoted, too, as many other of such answers of mine. It is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex to match the 7 chunks of whitespace separated non-whitespace chunks using

```
'~\S+(?:\s+\S+){6}~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZkPDmi/2/). To only match this string at the beginning of input, add `^` at the beginning.

**Details**

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+){6}` - 6 occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars.

[PHP code:](https://ideone.com/UWXAO1)

```
$str = "this line doesn\'t have seven words.\nThis line does has more than 7 but the regex is ignoring the first line.";
if (preg_match_all('/\S+(?:\s+\S+){6}/', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
echo "\n";
if (preg_match('/^\S+(?:\s+\S+){6}/', $str, $match)) {
    print_r($match[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this line doesn\'t have seven words.
This
    [1] => line does has more than 7 but
    [2] => the regex is ignoring the first line.
)

this line doesn\'t have seven words.
This
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion, you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php and craft a pattern to match the whitespace and not the words.

```
$text = 'i only want
to get the first
seven words from this text';

$sevenWords = array_slice( preg_split('/\s+/',$text), 0, 7 );

var_dump( $sevenWords );
```